# error: nothing to repeat at position 0 pd.read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to open a txt file with `sep='+++$+++` but I get that error.
This is the code:

```
pd.read_csv("dataset.txt", sep='+++$+++', engine='python')

# Error:
error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Sample of the txt file:

```
u0 +++$+++ u2 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ ['L276', 'L277']
u0 +++$+++ u2 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ ['L280', 'L281']
u0 +++$+++ u2 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ ['L363', 'L364']
u0 +++$+++ u2 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ ['L365', 'L366']
u0 +++$+++ u2 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ ['L367', 'L368']
u0 +++$+++ u2 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ ['L401', 'L402', 'L403']
u0 +++$+++ u2 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ ['L404', 'L405', 'L406', 'L407']
u0 +++$+++ u2 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ ['L575', 'L576']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
pd.read_csv('dataset.txt', sep='\+\+\+\$\+\+\+' , engine='python')
```

This is because both + and $ are considered special characters

Comment: thank you!! I've also added `encoding='ISO-8859-1'` parameter to `red_csv()`, for anyone that tries to use `'utf-8`' and fails too